# WPF TextBox Border when selected?

Tags: wpf, textbox, styling

I want to make a WPF TextBox have a DarkBlue border and thickness equal to 1. I want to make the WPF have this border ( DarkBlue, thickness set to 1 ) even when the TextBox is selected.

I tried doing this task by the following code. However, it doesn't work at all. **Any ideas or hints ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

```
  <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyLargeTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="80"/>

        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsMouseOver"    Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsMouseOver"    Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>


    </Style>
```

**P.S** Note that the text box does not have an IsSelected property.

Comment: "even when the TextBox is selected": what do you mean ? The border doesn't change when the TextBox is selected, so you don't need triggers at all... just put the setters in the style

Answer (score 23, accepted):

just see is this you want...

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="#FF825E5E" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem is due to having the Trigger Property value containing *TextBox*.  You just need the name of the property.

```
    <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyLargeTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="80"/>

        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [FocusVisualStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle.aspx) property of the FrameworkElement object (ancestor of TextBox). It's purpose is to define style applied when an element is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same logic for when "IsMouseOver" True as well  False. Change one and you should see something.