# What is that for an event

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a textbox that looks as follows:

[image]

And then when the mouse is moved over, it looks like:

[image]

As you can see on the second image, the textbox has a gray border.

My question is, what is that for an event that gets fired when I do mouseover on the textbox?
It is not the mouseover event.

Why am I so sure about it? Because the textbox takes the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="TbStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#b3ffff"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00e6e6"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404242"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#006666"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Brown"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
      </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

  </Style>
```

When I do mouseover, the border has the Brown color and a few seconds later gets the gray color again (like on the second picture above). But I want that the border stays Brown.

Comment: Try using MouseEnter and MouseLeave events

Comment: Have you tried this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798326/why-does-textbox-border-colour-insist-on-and-not-changing-in-wpf

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 Which solution do I have to take, to solve my problem.

Comment: Note that the trigger **is** working properly. The border thickness is adjusted to `1` when hovering over it. You can verify this better when choosing a different size than `1` and `4`. It’s just that the border brush is not correctly adjusted in the trigger for some odd reason.

Comment: @nguyenhoai890 I really do not know what to do. Thanks

Comment: @zero_coding you mean that you already tried with the solution set BorderThickness large than 1 and it does not affect? 
If yes, so I think the only way is adding new template for text box. Please read this one for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068.aspx

Comment: I saw some link that may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832085/wpf-textbox-border-when-selected